# Java - Why is Eclipse telling me my method must return type int?

Tags: java, eclipse, methods

I'm making a rock paper scissors game for a class assignment, and I'm trying to write a method that returns integers 1, 2, or 3 depending on whether the user wins, the computer wins, or it's a tie. We aren't allowed to simply return the message "You win!" or "You lose!" or "Tie!" within the method, we have to return integers. However, when I type the code out like so, I get a compiler error warning in Eclipse that tells me "This method must return a result of type int." Isn't that what I'm doing here? Help! 
Thanks!

```
public static int playGame(String userChoose) {
    System.out.println("Enter your choice.");
    userChoose=kbd.nextLine().toLowerCase();
    String computerChoose=computerChoose();
    if (userChoose.equals(computerChoose)) {
        return 3;
    }
    else if (userChoose.equals("rock")) {
        if (computerChoose.equals("scissors")) 
            return 1;
        else if (computerChoose.equals("paper")) 
            return 2;
    }
    else if (userChoose.equals("paper")) {
        if (computerChoose.equals("scissors")) 
            return 2;
        else if (computerChoose.equals("rock")) 
            return 1;
    } 
    else if (userChoose.equals("scissors")) {
        if (computerChoose.equals("paper")) 
            return 1; 
        else if (computerChoose.equals("rock")) 
            return 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: your if-else case does not cover all cases. add an `else` case for remaining results and return an int.

Answer (score 3):

Because you promised you would!

`public static int playGame(String userChoose)`

The `int` in there says "On my honor I swear I'll return an int"

If you don't deliver on that promise the compiler gets grumpy.

That means no matter what branch you take thru the code you must return an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Since your return statements are all inside one of your if-else clauses,
you need to give a *default return value* for the case when none of your if-else conditions are met.
Something like:

```java
public static int playGame(String userChoose) {
    System.out.println("Enter your choice.");
    userChoose=kbd.nextLine().toLowerCase();
    String computerChoose=computerChoose();
    if (userChoose.equals(computerChoose)) {
        return 3;
    }
    else if (userChoose.equals("rock")) {
        if (computerChoose.equals("scissors")) 
            return 1;
        else if (computerChoose.equals("paper")) 
            return 2;
    }
    else if (userChoose.equals("paper")) {
        if (computerChoose.equals("scissors")) 
            return 2;
        else if (computerChoose.equals("rock")) 
            return 1;
    } 
    else if (userChoose.equals("scissors")) {
        if (computerChoose.equals("paper")) 
            return 1; 
        else if (computerChoose.equals("rock")) 
            return 2;
    }
    return -1; //--> the default return value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler doesn't know that the input must be rock, paper or scissors. If you guard for the inputs then

```
else if (userChoose.equals("scissors")) {
```

should just be

```
else {
```

Or, add a default *error* return at the end of the method like

```
return -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

What if none of those if is validated

You have to provide a return value to solve this issue

```
 public static int playGame(String userChoose) {
System.out.println("Enter your choice.");
userChoose=kbd.nextLine().toLowerCase();
String computerChoose=computerChoose();
if (userChoose.equals(computerChoose)) {
    return 3;
}
else if (userChoose.equals("rock")) {
    if (computerChoose.equals("scissors")) 
        return 1;
    else if (computerChoose.equals("paper")) 
        return 2;
}
else if (userChoose.equals("paper")) {
    if (computerChoose.equals("scissors")) 
        return 2;
    else if (computerChoose.equals("rock")) 
        return 1;
} 
else if (userChoose.equals("scissors")) {
    if (computerChoose.equals("paper")) 
        return 1; 
    else if (computerChoose.equals("rock")) 
        return 2;
}
else
 return -1;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It's always best to use something like a return value variable, then set it using conditions and then return it at the end of the code. For example:

```
int retValue = 0;
...
else if (userChoose.equals("scissors")) {
   if (computerChoose.equals("paper")) 
      retValue = 1; 
   else if (computerChoose.equals("rock")) 
      retValue = 2;
   }
}
return retValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer has already been given by others: your conditional clauses didn't cover all the possible states.

The slightly longer answer: anytime your code is dealing with external input, you have to consider the possibility that the input is *wrong*. This is one of the core principles of programming.